# How to display links in storybook next to title?

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon

I'm trying to show 'copy' links when user hovers on heading:

[image]

In storybook documentation sometimes it works:
https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/mdx#documentation-only-mdx

And sometimes not:
https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-links

How do I enable them? What I've tried - I've copied code from storybook's github - I thought that top links somehow get mapped later to the headings, but no luck so far

```
-   [Basic example](#basic-example)
-   [MDX-Flavored CSF](#mdx-flavored-csf)

## Basic example

## MDX-Flavored CSF
```

Do I need any addons to handle that?

Comment: I found it renders here and somehow its not invoked for my headings https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/7035ea7389393da041985ebc491ee58dedb50d06/code/lib/blocks/src/blocks/mdx.tsx as OcticonHeader

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that headings ids are not generated by `remark-slug` package [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/7035ea7389393da041985ebc491ee58dedb50d06/code/lib/blocks/src/blocks/mdx.tsx) -- in `HeaderMdx` it doesn't go into `if` condition because no `id` was provided and function returns regular `<Header>` instead of `<HeaderWithOcticonAhchor>`

[image]

Based on this [thread](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/18395) this was broken after `6.4.19` and fix [was pushed](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/pull/18740/files) into `7.0.0`

So solutions are:

- downgrade, though its not obvious to me how to do that yet
- [upgrade](https://storybook.js.org/docs/7.0/react/configure/upgrading#automigrate-script) to `7.0.0` (which is in alpha18 as of now)
- [postinstall patching](https://scottspence.com/posts/patching-packages) of latest `6.5.0`